# Weak representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I have a question about the proof of Theorem 8.2.10 from "Topological Vector Spaces" by Narici & Beckenstein.

> Let $(X,Y,b)$ be a pairing of topological vector spaces over the field $\mathbb{K}$. If $g$ is a $\sigma(X,Y,b)$-continuous functional on $X$, then there exists some $y\in Y$ such that $g=b(\cdot,y)$.

They start with mentioning that continuity of a functional $f$ on a topological vector space $X$ is equivalent to $|f|\leq p$ for some continous seminorm $p$ on $X$. Then they continue: This means, that for a $\sigma(X,Y,b)$-continuous linear  functional $g$, there exist $y_1,\dots, y_n\in Y$ such that
$$|g|\leq\max_i |b(\cdot,y_i)|.$$
I just don't see how one implies the other.

Comment: I don't really know the context (or the exact definitions of the objects involved), but it seems to me that the authors are implicitly using the fact (?) that every weakly continuous seminorm is bounded from above by a function of the form you have on the right hand side.

Comment: $b:X\times Y\to \mathbb{K}$ is a bilinear map and $\sigma (X,Y,b)$ is the weakest topology on $X$ making all maps $b(\cdot,y):X\to\mathbb{K}$ continuous. Could you elaborate why every weakly continous seminorm is bounded above by such a function?

Comment: I guessed as much. To clarify, by "weakly continuous", I meant continuous with respect to this topology. I'm not sure why, I did not really think about it to be honest, it's just what I can gather from the structure of the argument alone (well, the part you described). My guess is it's probably either quite straightforward, or stated as a fact earlier in the book (most likely both).

Comment: This is just general locally convex theory: If $T_i:Y\to Z_i$ are linear maps into locally convex spaces $Z_i$ (in your case $T_x=b(x,\cdot)$) then the initial toplogy on $Y$ with respect to these maps (the coarsest one making all $T_i$ continuous) is given by all seminorms of the form $p(y)=\max\{p_i(T_i(y)):i\in E\}$ with finite sets $E$ and continuous seminorms $p_i$ on $Z_i$.